# I am an active member of the Communist Party of Greece, will I have trouble visiting the US?

Tags: visas, usa, standard-visitor-visas

I am a member of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communist_Party_of_Greece and I would like to visit an old friend in California, will I have some sort of trouble over there?

I plan on staying for 3 weeks.

Comment: How active? Do you hold any positions?

Comment: Are you well-known as a Communist politician or activist, or are you more a rank-and-file supporter? For example, do you give public speeches, participate in public debates, or publish books under your own name in support of Communism or is the extent of your participation more along the lines of carrying a card and paying dues?

Comment: Are you asking about "official" difficulty (visa's and such) or about how you will be treated by ordinary people here?

Comment: If you are not a well-known Communist public figure and keep your viewpoints reasonably to yourself, ordinary people will have no reason to treat you differently. I seriously doubt you will encounter problems from ordinary people even if they know you are a Communist as long as you follow basic safety precautions and common sense. Don't show up to a MAGA rally wearing a Mao suit and humming the Soviet anthem.

Answer (score 26):

No.  Membership in a communist party is only a ground of inadmissibility for immigrants, not for nonimmigrants.  See [8 USC 1182(a)(3)(D)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#a_3_D):

> (D) Immigrant membership in totalitarian party
>
> (i) In general
>
> Any immigrant who is or has been a member of or affiliated with the Communist or any other totalitarian party (or subdivision or affiliate thereof), domestic or foreign, is inadmissible.

(There are exceptions to this general provision, but you do not need to worry about them, because "immigrant" is defined at [8 USC 1101(a)(15)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1101#a_15) to exclude, among others, "visitors for business or pleasure"; see [8 USC 1101(a)(15)(B)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1101#a_15_B).)

Comment: [Volume 8, Part F, Chapter 3](https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-8-part-f-chapter-3) of the USCIS policy manual shows how this restriction is adjudicated, but your summary is correct that short-term visa-waiver or B visa visitors are not subject to it.

Comment: In this context, "The Communist party", is that any local party that happens to have "Communist" in their name? (And somehow that makes them totalitarian?)

Comment: @njzk2 see the section entitled "Communist or Any Other Totalitarian Party" at the link above for the full definition, but basically, yes, one of the qualifying sets of parties is "The Communist Party of any state of the United States, of any foreign state, or of any political or geographical subdivision of any foreign state." (i do not think this is sensible and am not trying to defend it, only to describe.)

Comment: @njzk2 most of the interesting things about this provision are off topic here, since this restriction only applies to immigrants.  Practical questions may be asked at [Expatriates.SE], legal questions such as those concerning interpretation and constitutionality may be asked at [Law.SE], and questions about the law's origins may be asked at [History.SE] or perhaps [Politics.SE].

Comment: @njzk2 in fact, see [Why is Communism singled out as a totalitarian party in US immigration laws?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/74756/6927) at [Politics.SE].

Answer (score 19):

Although membership in the Communist party in the past 2 years will make an immigrant inadmissible under INA 212(a)(3)(D) ([8 USC 1182](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title8-section1182&num=0&edition=prelim)(a)(3)(D); see [9 FAM 302.5-6](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM030205.html#M302_5_6) and [8 USCIS-PM F.3](https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-8-part-f-chapter-3) for more info), and membership in the Communist party in the past 10 years will make one ineligible for naturalization under INA 313(a)(2) ([8 USC 1424](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title8-section1424&num=0&edition=prelim)(a)(2); see [12 USCIS-PM D.7(D)(1)](https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-12-part-d-chapter-7#S-D-1)), there is no specific prohibition against Communist party members entering the US as nonimmigrants.

However, just because you don't have a ban doesn't mean that you will necessarily be able to enter -- immigration officers at entry have wide discretion to deny entry to most types of nonimmigrant status for pretty much anything they don't like, under the basis of "failure to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent". Since Communists aren't really a big problem in the US right now, I am guessing that you will probably be okay. But there are no guarantees.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138504/discussion-on-answer-by-user102008-i-am-an-active-member-of-the-communist-party).

Answer (score 8):

You won't be asked.

Assuming you're a Greek citizen you can travel to the US under the Visa Waiver scheme with an ESTA you apply for online. The ESTA does not ask about communist party affiliation.

With an ESTA you will quickly pass through immigration with some superficial questions about your reason to visit unless something has happened to make them suspicious of you.

Comment: IIRC the ESTA application *does* ask about social media accounts, so any content published by an applicant could potentially lead to a refusal

Comment: @Traveller: The social media account question is optional on the ESTA.

Comment: It's probably not necessary but also perhaps advisable to put controversial social media accounts on private or inactive while travelling across borders, with a reasonable justification for that just in case you get asked, like inability to moderate hostile replies while away, minor harassment or stalking you were recently subjected to, or anything else someone might want to go private or deactivate over.

Comment: @JackAidley Easy enough to locate just by searching the name though

Comment: @Traveller: that may, or may not, be so - depending on how our asker sets up their accounts - but, in the overwhelming majority of cases, an ESTA is approved without any additional checks by automated process.

Answer (score 4):

While certainly the INA is the relevant legislation here, there are quite a lot of other rules so it is nice to find a more or less up-to-date 
[Clarification of U.S. Visa Law Pertaining to Communist Party Members](https://np.usembassy.gov/clarification-of-u-s-visa-law-pertaining-to-communist-party-members/) from the U.S. Embassy in Nepal posted on October 6, 2020 -- it confirms what the others have posted, that you are welcome as a visitor. Immigration is complicated.

My summary is this, compiled by copying the relevant parts and changing nothing

> there has been no change to our policy, or to our decades-old law regarding members of communist parties who are traveling to the United States: the INA does not affect people wanting to visit the United States temporarily with a non-immigrant visa.

The full text is below.

---

We are concerned that a few news stories have published misleading information about U.S. visas.  We’d like to clarify that there has been no change to our policy, or to our decades-old law regarding members of communist parties or totalitarian regimes who are traveling or immigrating to the United States.  Nepal Communist Party members are not automatically barred from immigrating to the United States.  Each visa case is adjudicated on an individual basis.

U.S. Citizens and Immigration Services (USCIS) recently issued administrative guidance – essentially an instruction manual – to USCIS officers for the immigration applications of people already within the United States.  News about this administrative guidance has caused confusion.

In 1952, the U.S. Congress passed the Immigration and Nationality Act (INA), which barred people from immigrating to the United States on the basis of membership in, or affiliation with a Communist or any other totalitarian party.

The law provides for many exceptions and waivers, allowing party members to immigrate to the U.S. if otherwise qualified.  The INA does not affect people wanting to visit the United States temporarily with a non-immigrant visa.

The United States welcomes those with diverse backgrounds and beliefs to apply for visas.  We also respect Nepal’s multiparty democracy and will continue to work with the country’s elected government and people to advance bilateral ties and strengthen democracy as we’ve been doing for the past 73 years.